Webcam video stream for capturing photo not working
   error in dev tool console- app.js:20  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener')
at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (app.js:20:19)

(anonymous) @ app.js:20
app.js:9 Camera stream obtained
app.js:13  Error accessing camera: TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'srcObject')
I am trying to get access to webcam and display video stream for capturing photo. I am  getting consent for camera access i.e. popup message and when I allow the access the front camera indicator light is coming but there is nothing visible on webpage and capture photo button is also not working. I searched a lot but couldn't find anything.
Below is the code for it:
app.js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    const video = document.getElementById('video');
    const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    const captureButton = document.getElementById('capture');
    const photoData = document.getElementById('photo_data');

    // Get access to the camera
    if (navigator.mediaDevices && navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
        navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true }).then(function(stream) {
            console.log("Camera stream obtained");
            video.srcObject = stream;
            video.play();
        }).catch(function(error) {
            console.log("Error accessing camera: " + error);
            alert("Could not access the camera. Please check permissions.");
        });
    } else {
        alert("getUserMedia is not supported by your browser.");
    }

    // Capture photo
    captureButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
        const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, 320, 240);
        const dataURL = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
        photoData.value = dataURL;
        canvas.style.display = 'block';
    });
});

function submitForm() {
    const photoData = document.getElementById('photo_data').value;
    if (!photoData) {
        alert("Please capture a photo before submitting the form.");
        return false;
    }
    return true; // Ensures the form is submitted
}

This is my .php file from which I am accessing the webcam feature
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Visitor Form</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container mt-5 print-area">
        <h2>Visitor Form</h2>
        <form method="post" action="visitor_form.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return submitForm()">
            <div class="form-group">
    <label for="photo">Photo</label>
    <div style="display: flex; align-items: center;">
        <video id="video" width="320" height="240" autoplay></video>
        <button type="button" id="capture" class="btn btn-secondary" style="margin-left: 10px;">Capture Photo</button>
        <canvas id="canvas" width="320" height="240" style="display: none;"></canvas>
        <input type="hidden" name="photo_data" id="photo_data">
    </div>
</div>
    <script src="../js/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

Screenshot of the error:


Maybe you can solve it by changint context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, 320, 240); to context.drawImage(video.srcObject, 0, 0, 320, 240);.

@KLASANGUI i tried it but still not working

Why is this tagged with PHP?

Oh, so, your <video> is not displaying the camera stream because there's no permission... Note that to get permission, you need a user triggered event to happen. So, you should hide your form and show it only after asking for permission through a button click... Your DOMContentLoaded event listener should be attached to this button click event instead and run only after you asked camera permissions (await navigator.permissions.query({name: 'camera'})).

@KLASANGUI
i added this also but still not working ,i don't know why it's not working
